# What’s the difference between 制定 and 制订?

Tags: word-choice

I see both terms being used quite often, and both seem to mean “to formulate/create/come up (with a plan)”.

People often say 制定计划, but many others say 制订计划 too. Both look sound to me. What is the difference?

Comment: Are there some instances where one is much more suitable than the other? Like how it is better to say 这家工厂制造产品 instead of 制作产品

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I have found that there isn’t much practical difference between the two terms.

However, **制订** refers more to the actual thinking and creative aspect of a plan, as in its 创造性, while **制定** refers more to the confirmative and definitive aspect of a plan being put in place, or its 权威性.

Comment: Right, if something is created by a person or company, more likely it's 制订. if it's like a legislation, it's more likely 制定

Comment: Good job. To be honest, could be confusing for most cn people. And often clarified and examed at school.